# VBA -Linking a form(Textbox) with the correct cells but by adding data sequentially?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

Hello i am trying to add data by using the VBA form , yet i want to add the data sequentially --> i have written the following

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click()
Dim Name As String
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("DataBase").Range("A:A"))
Name = Worksheets("DataBase").Range("B2").Value

Worksheets("DataBase").Range("B2").Value = txtName.Text

Sheets("DataBase").Cells(LastRow + 1, 1).Value = LastRow
Sheets("DataBase").Cells(LastRow + 1, 2).Value = usrfrm.txtName.Value


End Sub
```

so i have in my single sheet which is ("DataBase") two columns **NO** to add the sequence and **Name** to add names.

the problem i have is that when i add new data it replicates in the first row and the last one

***Screenshot:***

[image]

Comment: What is the use of this line ? ---> `Name = Worksheets("DataBase").Range("B2").Value`. This line `Worksheets("DataBase").Range("B2").Value = txtName.Text` is causing cell B2 fill with whatever name in the textbox, then that's why it "replicate" the whatever name in the textbox to cell B2 (the first row of data) and to cell B4 (the last row of data). Try to remove this line `Worksheets("DataBase").Range("B2").Value = txtName.Text`, then step-run the code (F8) in vba editor.

Answer (score 0):

The code below will work if called from the UserForm's code module, for example, in a procedure that is triggered by pressing the *OK* button in the form.

```
Dim Name As String
Dim LastRow As Long

With Worksheets("DataBase")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    .Cells(LastRow, 1).Value = LastRow
    .Cells(LastRow, 2).Value = txtName.Value
End With
```

Comment: Hi there thanks a lot man you look professional , but i have inserted a table so it going to skip two rows